# How to change the way LibGDX scales images?

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm using FillViewport and OrthographicCamera. LibGDX is scaling my images rather badly - jagged edges, visible pixels. How can I change the scaling method?

by the way, I'm pretty sure the issue isn't my images. I've scaled them using imaging software and they look a lot better than when LibGDX scales them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is probably because of [Texture Filters](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/Texture.TextureFilter.html). And it's not LibGdx problem either, but OpenGL's.

You can set filters for Libgdx textures using `setFilter()` method. For eg., try setting the filter to:

`yourTexture.setFilter(TextureFilter.MipMapLinearNearest,TextureFilter.Nearest);`

[Here's the detailed explanation](http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=1403) written by Mario himself.